# Using GLFX.js on a full HTML page

Tags: software-engineering, html5, webgl, web, html

I have a friend who is developing a game for HTML, and wants me to implement GLFX into the site page.
The problem is GLFX was designed specifically for use with the HTML5 Canvas, which he isn't using, and wants the effect across the whole site page, not just an area; here in lies the problem.

As GLFX was designed for Canvas objects specifically, and there are no obvious alternatives for creating CRT/Arcade-esque effects on websites, I seem to be at an impasse with my current understanding.

I have set up one of my own little side projects on a localhost on my PC in hopes that I can get it to work with a plane website.

Has anyone here had experience with GLFX, or know how I would implement it's effects onto the body of an entire site?

Here is the link he sent me to follow, it contains the "scanlines" image as well.

Sorry in advance if I have posted this in the wrong place, but I couldn't find StackExchange's Web Development community.

http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2012/08/17/webgl-fake-crt-html5.html

Comment: I'd say you're in the right place, because a game developer would be much more familiar with the specific effect you are trying to achieve. Though being tagged as `game-design` is probably keeping the right people from seeing it. I've edited the tags to include `programming` and `webgl`